Python serial send byte array with byte values
I would like to send such array for example via pyserial:
[49, 56, 48] or [82]

I tried such solution before sending:
print(list(str(180).encode()))

And it gives me array as I want. But when I tried to send it via pySerial, it said that I need to have buffer instead of list. In general I'm trying to get some analogue from kotlin:
byteArrayOf('O'.code.toByte())


"70".toByteArray()

Which gives me such arrays for sending them to Arduino. I tried sending maps, dicts, and so on, but did not succeed. Whether it's possible to have something similar in Python?
python sending code:
import json
import struct

import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem14401', 9600)

data = [49, 56, 48]
ser.write(json.dumps(data) + '\n')
ser.write(str('R').encode())
ser.write(str(80).encode())


encode() returns a byte array, so just use .write(str(180).encode())

I tried that too :( and it did not reach the arduino script at all

Then you have a different problem.

Please post a [mre].

Is the Arduino side perhaps expecting a newline or other terminator character?

If you stringify a python data structure and expect the arduino to be able to operate on the same data structure, your arduino code will have to parse the data from the serial port first, which is a non-trivial task if the data structure can vary.

@mkrieger1, not sure because from mobile app which I also made by kotlin all is ok :D

@Barmar, check please the updated question

@jasonharper, check please, I updated the question, but not sure that I have terminator expectation :(

We need to see the Python code, not C code.

updated in the question

This might give you some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/a/78505898/2836621

@MarkSetchell, thank you for your help :)

This works for me on Windows. Obviously you need to replace my 'COM10'.
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600, write_timeout=1)

time.sleep(4)   # Wait for Arduino to reboot

# bytes_to_send = [65]
bytes_to_send = [65, 66, 67, 68, 69]

count = 0
while True:
    for byte in bytes_to_send:
        ser.write([byte])
        print(f"{count} Sent {byte}")
        count += 1

The four second delay is needed because the Arduino reboots when you open the serial port.
